# How I can get multiple data flow in real time?

Tags: python, database

I really want to know how can I get multiple json data in real-time? Specifically, what if I have:

- The web link or API like https://abcd.xyz/snapshot?boll=xxx, with boll named xxx, I can change this xxx to other name to get data of other boll.
- The data get from this link is under json type and easy to preprocess with Python
- All the data is wished to be save on local database such as MySQL,...

Now, the requirement is that I need to get about 50 to 100 data of the boll in real-time. There will be new data in anytime (0.025s, or 0.5s or more/less) that not pre-defined, the data is update naturally if there have any change.

Currently, I just using get method (request.get) for each 0.5s, however, it will be the gap between if there is any data updated at 0.25s.

As desired, I wonder that is there any method to get data continuously from the links above without losing any updated data and still keep the server run without lag.

So could you guy have any recommendation on any language or tool to get this task done. Until now I'm just working on Python for nearly all data task

Thank you so much!

Comment: Python will work fine for this.

Comment: Could you specific any method or any tutorial sources?

Comment: Not really. You haven't defined your requirements for real-time either (for just a snapshot API endpoint, you'd have to repeatedly poll it for new information).

Comment: I have updated my expected output, could you help me?

Comment: There's no way to guarantee you never lose any version of the data unless the server cooperates with you to push every update to you.